# PostgreSQL - Share data on Network drive

Tags: postgresql, database-design, postgresql-performance

I currently use a simple *Microsoft Access database*, stored on the company Network Drive, for my department's data needs. This works quite well as everybody in my team has access to the shared folder where the database is stored, and can thus query it easily at anytime.

I'm now trying to replace this Microsoft Access database by a **PostgreSQL** database, but I'm a bit puzzled as to how to create a similar "shared" database in PostgreSQL. I currently have a PostgreSQL server hosted at "localhost", but from what I understand; this is an instance running on my own computer which becomes unavailable as soon as I shut down my computer.

So, my question is: what is the best practice to share data with colleagues (using PosgreSQL) so everyone can connect and interact with it at any time, and so everyone always has the latest updated data?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can only "share" it by running a Postgres instance on a server (=computer) that accepts connections from the other computers. You can't just put the files on a network share. A database _server_ has a completely different architecture than MS Access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm a bit puzzled as to how to create a similar "shared" database in PostgreSQL.

(Sorry if this is a bit "down" on MS Access but ...)
Let's start with a fundamental Truth about [proper] databases:

```
Database != File
```

You should think of a database as a *process* that runs on a machine and does work on behalf of other applications.  [Largely] *Forget* about the fact that there are *files* underneath it.  Treat it as a logical thing.  Use database tools for database tasks (no copying database files around while the cluster is running, for example!)

To *share* your postgres cluster, you start the postmaster process and then connect to that running process using a Postgres-compatible client.  Interactively, that's often **psql**.

> ... this is an instance running on my own computer which becomes unavailable as soon as I shut down my computer.

Correct.
You need to acquire a *server machine* that you can leave running *all* the time, on which you install and operate PostgreSQL.
This has the *added benefit* that you can have *both* your locally running instance, in which you can develop and test things and a *separate* Production instance, where the real thing runs and that everyone else uses (and neither can "break" the other).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was missing the _server machine_ thing, much clearer now!

Comment: @BJ2M - if you're happy with the answer, then please mark it as correct and/or helpful - that way, people with similar issues who search will be more likely to find this thread!